# Testing Mongoose models with Jest

Tags: javascript, mongoose, jestjs

I am trying to test my Mongoose models with Jest. My model looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const slug = require('slugs');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const cinemaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: 'Please enter a cinema name'
  },
  slug: String,
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  capacity: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'Please enter a capacity'
  }
});

cinemaSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (!this.isModified('name')) {
    next();
    return
  }
  this.slug = slug(this.name);
  next();
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cinema', cinemaSchema)
```

I have written some tests below, but when I try to run them and access their result, I receive undefined. I'm using the `.validate` function here because I don't want to actually hit my database.

The test looks like this. I have removed the expectation because I simply want to access the errors:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Cinema = require('./Cinema');

describe('Cinema', () => {
  it('Should return an error if a number is passed as the name', (done) => {
    const cinema = new Cinema({name: 2, description: 'good', capacity: 1});
    cinema.validate(response => {
      console.log(response);
      done();
    });

  })
})
```

Any idea why I am getting undefined here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because mongoose will try to cast the cinema `name` to string and it's successful doing that. Try instead changing the `capacity` to a string: `capacity: 'saasd'`
You will get something like:

```
{
  ValidationError: Cinema validation failed: capacity: Cast to Number failed for value "saasd" at path "capacity"
        at ValidationError.Object.<anonymous>.ValidationError.inspect (/Users/fabio/playground/mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:56:24)
        at formatValue (util.js:430:38)
        at inspect (util.js:324:10)
        at format (util.js:191:12)
        at CustomConsole.log (/Users/fabio/playground/mongoose/node_modules/jest-util/build/Console.js:135:53)
        at cinema.validate.response (/Users/fabio/playground/mongoose/cinema.test.js:12:15)
        at /Users/fabio/playground/mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1432:5
        at /Users/fabio/playground/mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1564:9
        at /Users/fabio/playground/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:135:16
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
   errors: {
     capacity: MongooseError {
       message: 'Cast to Number failed for value "saasd" at path "capacity"',
       name: 'CastError',
       stringValue: '"saasd"',
       kind: 'Number',
       value: 'saasd',
       path: 'capacity',
       reason: [Object]
     }
   },
   _message: 'Cinema validation failed',
   name: 'ValidationError'
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for your help.